# Error XMLHttpRequest while sending sending data with https.post

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send some data to a .php file on my server in order to update my database.

But when i run my code i get this error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

Here is the code i am running:

```
class DbUpdate {
  Future<void> UpdateUser(String groupID, List<String> uData) async {
    print("dbUpdate");
    final response =  await http.post( Uri.https("myserver", "myphp.php"),
    body: {
      "group":groupID,
      "name":uData[0],
      "D1":uData[1],
      "D2":uData[2]
    });
    print (response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running on Web ?

Comment: Maybe `myphp.hp` should be `myphp.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the error is coming from the server side.

The error disapears after adding some code in the header of the .php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
```

I put it at this location:

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

    include "db.php";

   ....
```